# I add application preference in device setting

Tags: android

How can I add application preference in device setting. I want to my preference setting be part of device setting opinion. My application setting can be appeared or displayed in device setting list.

Any API i need to use or keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your own firmware. SDK applications cannot modify the roster of "device settings".